# update from ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: upgrade

I have been using ubuntu 14.04 for a couple of years, however starting to have some problems in installing a separate application due to not being on version 16.

I've tried to install several times over the past year, however had challenges, which I need to persevere through this time (I've given up on previous attempts!).

When I try to install to ubuntu 16 the first issue I have identified is that I'm not on the latest version of 14.04 - I believe I'm on 14.04.03 where the latest is 14.04.04. The message I get is that I don't have all the prerequisites installed for v16.

I've therefore tried updating to 14.04.04 (so that I can proceed to go to v16), however every time I try installing through the software centre I am told:

"Failed to download package files. Check your internet connection".

I appreciate that this is an issue others have experienced and have spent a couple of hours googling this evening but have reached the end of my tether. :)

To fix myself, I've tried the following (I'm not a technical person):

1. moving from a wireless to wired connection (although my internet is otherwise fine)
2. changing the server to "main", different ones in my country or "best server"
3. running various pieces of code I've found on help articles (most of which I don't understand fully).

Any guidance would be much appreciated - I don't want to revert to windows but afraid I will have to if can't resolve this issue. :)

Thanks!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71276/discussion-on-question-by-hopin-update-from-ubuntu-14-04-to-16-04).